# Switch cannot be resolved to a type, how to use in gingerbread

Tags: android, eclipse, api, switch-statement

How to use Switch(android.widget.Switch) in Gingerbread(level 9)`Switch button;`?, instead of level 14 and above. android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" compiler = 2.3(level9). If compiler is set to api level 14 and above no errors. Question is How to use in  switch in gingerbread.

Comment: you have to implement it on your own, or check if somebody already did it

Comment: @ blackbelt, can you provide any snippets or example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch was introduced in api 14+ . you can use [this](https://github.com/ankri/SwitchCompatLibrary) library or ,

also you can create it by own, take reference [here](http://ankri.de/switch-button-for-android-2-3-gingerbread/) -

Answer (score 0):

Please use the custom switch from [here](https://github.com/ankri/SwitchCompatLibrary). Which will backport to `Froyo, Gingerbread & Honeycomb`